# cocoa - executing stuff, need to open window, get input, then continue w/o reentering runloop

Tags: macos, window, subprocess, runloop

Is there any way to do this?

Right now, I get called, I'm doing things, I have to open a window to ask for input, then I have to FINISH doing things before I return from the original call.

If I enter the runloop for the window, it never ends or returns control to me.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it -- [NSApp runModalForWindow: window] -- that runs JUST the loop for the window, and when you stop it, control returns to you, leaving the main run loop undisturbed.

What I was doing was [NSApp run], which runs everything, and so when the window issued the stop, everything did.